# mongo: command not found on Mac OSX even though it's in the PATH

Tags: macos, node.js, mongodb, path, terminal

I'm trying to use mongodb on my Mac for a nodeJS app. I followed the steps given [here](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-mac-os-x/) to install mongo.

First of all, I wanted to know if adding mongodb path to the PATH with "nano .profile", or with "vim .bash_profile" is the same ? I'm used to using "nano .profile" and I want to know what are the differences.

Then, I added the path to mongodb in the .profile but when I try to use the command "mongo", it tells me "command not found". Although, when I manually type /usr/local/mongodb/bin/mongo (which is the path that I added in .profile), it works. I don't understand what's going on and the only solutions I find on the Internet are modifying the .profile, but mine seems correct to me.

Thanks for you help.

Mat

Comment: Also note you put DIRECTORIES in your PATH, not single files. So `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mongodb/bin` is good but adding `/usr/local/mongodb/bin/mongo` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know what are the differences.

Do a web search for ".bash_profile .profile". Stackoverflow's guidelines require "thoroughly researched" questions. There are countless detailed articles on this topic.

To get things working try typing `exec $SHELL` to reload your shell. If your PATH is correctly set up, typing `mongo` should work. Another command to be aware of is `rehash` which you need when you add a new program to an existing directory on your PATH because the shell basically scans the entire PATH and makes a lookup table, but when a new command program gets installed after that, the shell doesn't automatically notice. That's what `rehash` is for.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works now I think the shell wasn't reloaded. I did exec $SHELL and close+reopen terminal.